# hidden form in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to show a form once a certain button is clicked. i tried some methods like

1)i add the form initially to the HTML and give it a hidden property then change it with .show() or .css() my problem is it takes a space of the page.

2) i used .appened() to add the form but the form is too long and it never works.

what's the best way to hide an element first then show it in JQuery ?

Comment: the best way is to `hide` it then `show` it... can you show the markup

Comment: If you hide it using the `visibility` property, it will take up space. Use `display: none` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assigned the wrong css. Use `display:none;`:

```
<form id="myform" style="display:none;">
  ...
</form>
```

And, to show it:

```
$("#myform").show();
```

This works, guaranteed. With `display:none;`, it doesn't occupy space. You certainly may have used `visibility:hidden;` **that** was your mistake (because it does occupy space)

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: It works guaranteed, but if users have JavaScript disabled they won't ever be able to see the form.

Comment: It works guaranteed for the conditions of the question. (uses jquery and css)

Comment: thank you so much . it was very helpful and yes i was using the visibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#formID").hide();
    $("#buttonID").click(function() {
        $("#formID").show();
    });
});
```

You can see an example fiddle of this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/erCEq/1/). Note that this hides the form using jQuery, so if users have JavaScript disabled they will still get to see it. If you hide the form with a CSS property directly, users without JavaScript will never be able to see it.

Comment: okay so if i did it that way formID wont mess up my css and take space ?

Comment: The "formID" can be anything you want. If you're already using an ID on your form (for CSS or whatever) then you can use the existing ID.

Comment: Users with javascript (99%) will see the form visible and then see it disappear (because it will be visible until the document is ready)